# Reconstructing input to encoder from output

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, combinatorics, constraint-programming

I would like to understand how to solve the Codility [ArrayRecovery](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/92-tasks_from_indeed_prime_2016_college_coders_challenge/array_recovery/) challenge, but I don't even know what branch of knowledge to consult. Is it combinatorics, optimization, computer science, set theory, or something else?

**Edit:**
The branch of knowledge to consult is [constraint programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming), particularly [constraint propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_consistency). You also need some [combinatorics](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/math/combinatorics/basics-of-combinatorics/tutorial/) to know that if you take *k* numbers at a time from the range [1..*n*], with the restriction that no number can be bigger than the one before it, that works out to be
*(n+k-1)!/k!(n-1)!* possible combinations
which is the same as the number of *combinations with replacements* of *n* things taken *k* at a time, which has the mathematical notation <sub><sub>[image: nCRk]</sub></sub>. You can read about why it works out like that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3051435/29642).

Peter Norvig provides an excellent example of how to solve this kind of problem with his [Sudoku solver](http://norvig.com/sudoku.html).

---

You can read the full description of the ArrayRecovery problem via the link above. The short story is that there is an *encoder* that takes a *sequence of integers* in the range 1 up to some given limit (say 100 for our purposes) and *for each element of the input sequence* outputs *the most recently seen integer that is smaller than the current input, or 0 if none exists*.

```
input 1, 2, 3, 4 => output 0, 1, 2, 3
input 2, 4, 3 => output 0, 2, 2
```

The full task is, given the output (and the range of allowable input), figure out how many possible inputs could have generated it. But before I even get to that calculation, I'm not confident about how to even approach formulating the equation. That is what I am asking for help with. (Of course a full solution would be welcome, too, if it is explained.)

I just look at some possible outputs and wonder. Here are some sample encoder outputs and the inputs I can come up with, with `*` meaning any valid input and something like `> 4` meaning any valid input greater than 4. If needed, inputs are referred to as `A1, A2, A3, ...` (1-based indexing)

#### Edit #2

Part of the problem I was having with this challenge is that I did not manually generate the exactly correct sets of possible inputs for an output. I believe the set below is correct now. Look at this answer's edit history if you want to see my earlier mistakes.

```
output #1: 0, 0, 0, 4 
possible inputs: [>= 4, A1 >= * >= 4, 4, > 4]                     

output #2: 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4          # A5 ↴  See more in discussion below
possible inputs: [>= 2, A1 >= * >=2, 2, 3, 4, > 4]

output #3: 0, 0, 0, 4, 3, 1
possible inputs: none # [4, 3, 1, 1 >= * > 4, 4, > 1] but there is no number 1 >= * > 4
```

The second input sequence is very tightly constrained compared to the first just by adding 2 more outputs. The third sequence is so constrained as to be impossible.

But the set of constraints on A5 in example #2 is a bit harder to articulate. Of course A5 > O5, that is the basic constraint on all the inputs. But any output > A4 and after O5 has to appear in the input after A4, so A5 has to be an element of the set of numbers that comes after A5 that is also > A4. Since there is only 1 such number (A6 == 4), A5 has to be it, but it gets more complicated if there is a longer string of numbers that follow. *(Editor's note: actually it doesn't.)*

As the output set gets longer, I worry these constraints just get more complicated and harder to get right. I cannot think of any data structures for efficiently representing these in a way that leads to efficiently calculating the number of possible combinations. I also don't quite see how to algorithmically add constraint sets together.

Here are the constraints I see so far for any given A<sub>n</sub>

- A<sub>n</sub> > O<sub>n</sub>
- A<sub>n</sub> <= min(Set of other possible numbers from O<sub>1</sub> to <sub>n-1</sub> > O<sub>n</sub>). How to define the set of possible numbers greater than O<sub>n</sub>?

  1. Numbers greater than O<sub>n</sub> that came after the most recent occurrence of O<sub>n</sub> in the input
- A<sub>n</sub> >= max(Set of other possible numbers from O<sub>1</sub> to <sub>n-1</sub> < O<sub>n</sub>). How to define the set of possible numbers less than O<sub>n</sub>?

  1. Actually this set is empty because O<sub>n</sub> is, by definition, the largest *possible* number from the previous input sequence. (Which it not to say it is strictly the largest number from the previous input sequence.)
  2. Any number smaller than O<sub>n</sub> that came before the last occurrence of it in the input would be ineligible because of the "nearest" rule. No numbers smaller that O<sub>n</sub> could have occurred after the most recent occurrence because of the "nearest" rule and because of the transitive property: if A<sub>i</sub> < O<sub>n</sub> and A<sub>j</sub> < A<sub>i</sub> then A<sub>j</sub> < O<sub>n</sub>
- Then there is the set theory:

  1. A<sub>n</sub> must be an element of the set of unaccounted-for elements of the set of O<sub>n+1</sub> to O<sub>m</sub>, where m is the smallest m > n such that O<sub>m</sub> < O<sub>n</sub>. Any output after such O<sub>m</sub> and larger than O<sub>m</sub> (which A<sub>n</sub> is) would have to appear as or after A<sub>m</sub>.
  2. An element is unaccounted-for if it is seen in the output but does not appear in the input in a position that is consistent with the rest of the output. Obviously I need a better definition than this in order to code and algorithm to calculate it.

It seems like perhaps some kind of set theory and/or combinatorics or maybe linear algebra would help with figuring out the number of possible sequences that would account for all of the unaccounted-for outputs and fit the other constraints. *(Editor's note: actually, things never get that complicated.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below passes all of Codility's tests. The OP added a `main` function to use it on the command line.

The constraints are not as complex as the OP thinks. In particular, there is never a situation where you need to add a restriction that an input be an element of some set of specific integers seen elsewhere in the output. Every input position has a well-defined minimum and maximum.

The only complication to that rule is that sometimes the maximum is "the value of the previous input" and that input itself has a range. But even then, all the values like that are consecutive and have the same range, so the number of possibilities can be calculated with basic combinatorics, and those inputs as a group are independent of the other inputs (which only serve to set the range), so the possibilities of that group can be combined with the possibilities of other input positions by simple multiplication.

#### Algorithm overview

The algorithm makes a single pass through the output array updating the possible numbers of input arrays after every *span*, which is what I am calling repetitions of numbers in the output. (You might say maximal subsequences of the output where every element is identical.) For example, for output `0,1,1,2` we have three spans: `0`, `1,1` and `2`. When a new span begins, the number of possibilities for the previous span is calculated.

This decision was based on a few observations:

- For *spans* longer than 1 in length, the minimum value of the input
  allowed in the first position is whatever the value is of the input
  in the second position. Calculating the number of possibilities of a
  span is straightforward combinatorics, but the standard formula
  requires knowing the range of the numbers and the length of the span.
- Every time the value of the
  output changes (and a new span beings), that strongly constrains the value of the previous span:

  1. When the output goes up, the only possible reason is that the previous input was the value of the new, higher output and the input corresponding to the position of the new, higher output, was even higher.
  2. When an output goes down, new constraints are established, but those are a bit harder to articulate.  The algorithm stores *stairs* (see below) in order to quantify the constraints imposed when the output goes down

The aim here was to confine the range of possible values for every *span*. Once we do that accurately, calculating the number of combinations is straightforward.

Because the encoder backtracks looking to output a number that relates to the input in 2 ways, both smaller and closer, we know we can throw out numbers that are larger and farther away. After a small number appears in the output, no larger number from before that position can have any influence on what follows.

So to confine these ranges of input when the output sequence decreased, we need to store *stairs* - a list of increasingly larger possible values for the position in the original array. E.g for `0,2,5,7,2,4` stairs build up like this: `0`, `0,2`, `0,2,5`, `0,2,5,7`, `0,2`, `0,2,4`.

Using these bounds we can tell for sure that the number in the position of the second `2` (next to last position in the example) must be in `(2,5]`, because `5` is the next stair. If the input were greater than 5, a 5 would have been output in that space instead of a 2. Observe, that if the last number in the encoded array was not `4`, but `6`, we would exit early returning `0`, because we know that the previous number couldn't be bigger than `5`.

The complexity is `O(n*lg(min(n,m)))`.

#### Functions

- `CombinationsWithReplacement` - counts [number of combinations with replacements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474741/formula-for-combinations-with-replacement) of size `k` from `n` numbers. E.g. for `(3, 2)` it counts `3,3`, `3,2`, `3,1`, `2,2`, `2,1`, `1,1`, so returns `6` It is the same as `choose(n - 1 + k, n - 1)`.
- `nextBigger` - finds next bigger element in a range. E.g. for `4` in sub-array `1,2,3,4,5` it returns `5`, and in sub-array `1,3` it returns its parameter `Max`.
- `countSpan` (lambda) - counts how many different combinations a span **we have just passed** can have. Consider span `2,2` for `0,2,5,7,2,2,7`.

  1. When `curr` gets to the final position, `curr` is `7` and `prev` is the final `2` of the `2,2` span.
  2. It computes maximum and minimum possible values of the `prev` span. At this point stairs consist of `2,5,7` then maximum possible value is `5` (`nextBigger` after `2` in the `stair 2,5,7`). A value of greater than `5` in this span would have output a `5`, not a `2`.
  3. It computes a minimum value for the span (which is the minimum value for every element in the span), which is `prev` at this point, (remember `curr` at this moment equals to `7` and `prev` to `2`). We know for sure that in place of the final `2` output, the original input has to have `7`, so the minimum is `7`. (This is a consequence of the "output goes up" rule.  If we had `7,7,2` and `curr` would be `2` then the minimum for the previous span (the `7,7`) would be `8` which is `prev + 1`.
  4. It adjusts the number of combinations. For a span of length *L* with a range of *n* possibilities (1+max-min), there are [image: k combinations with replacement of n] possibilities, with *k* being either *L* or *L-1* depending on what follows the span.

     - For a span followed by a *larger* number, like `2,2,7`, *k = L - 1* because the last position of the `2,2` span has to be `7` (the value of the first number after the span).
     - For a span followed by a *smaller* number, like `7,7,2`, *k = L* because 
       the last element of `7,7` has no special constraints.
  5. Finally, it calls `CombinationsWithReplacement` to find out the number of branches (or possibilities), computes new `res` partial results value (remainder values in the modulo arithmetic we are doing), and returns new `res` value and `max` for further handling.
- `solution` - iterates over the given Encoder Output array. In the main loop, while in a span it counts the span length, and at span boundaries it updates `res` by calling `countSpan` and possibly updates the *stairs*.

  - If the current span consists of a bigger number than the previous one, then:

    1. Check validity of the next number. E.g `0,2,5,2,7` is invalid input, becuase there is can't be `7` in the next-to-last position, only `3`, or `4`, or `5`.
    2. It updates the stairs. When we have seen only `0,2`, the stairs are `0,2`, but after the next `5`, the stairs become `0,2,5`.
  - If the current span consists of a smaller number then the previous one, then:

    1. It updates stairs. When we have seen only `0,2,5`, our stairs are `0,2,5`, but after we have seen `0,2,5,2` the stairs become `0,2`.
  - After the main loop it accounts for the last span by calling `countSpan` with `-1` which triggers the "output goes down" branch of calculations.
- `normalizeMod`, `extendedEuclidInternal`, `extendedEuclid`, `invMod` - these auxiliary functions help to deal with modulo arithmetic.

<sub>For stairs I use storage for the encoded array, as the number of stairs never exceeds current position.</sub>

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

const int Modulus = 1'000'000'007;

int CombinationsWithReplacement(int n, int k);

template <class It>
auto nextBigger(It begin, It end, int value, int Max) {
    auto maxIt = std::upper_bound(begin, end, value);
    auto max = Max;
    if (maxIt != end) {
        max = *maxIt;
    }
    return max;
}

auto solution(std::vector<int> &B, const int Max) {
    auto res = 1;
    const auto size = (int)B.size();
    auto spanLength = 1;
    auto prev = 0;
    // Stairs is the list of numbers which could be smaller than number in the next position
    const auto stairsBegin = B.begin();
    // This includes first entry (zero) into stairs
    // We need to include 0 because we can meet another zero later in encoded array
    // and we need to be able to find in stairs
    auto stairsEnd = stairsBegin + 1;

    auto countSpan = [&](int curr) {
        const auto max = nextBigger(stairsBegin, stairsEnd, prev, Max);
        // At the moment when we switch from the current span to the next span
        // prev is the number from previous span and curr from current.
        // E.g. 1,1,7, when we move to the third position cur = 7 and prev = 1.
        // Observe that, in this case minimum value possible in place of any of 1's can be at least 2=1+1=prev+1.
        // But if we consider 7, then we have even more stringent condition for numbers in place of 1, it is 7
        const auto min = std::max(prev + 1, curr);
        const bool countLast = prev > curr;
        const auto branchesCount = CombinationsWithReplacement(max - min + 1, spanLength - (countLast ? 0 : 1));
        return std::make_pair(res * (long long)branchesCount % Modulus, max);
    };

    for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        const auto curr = B[i];
        if (curr == prev) {
            ++spanLength;
        }
        else {
            int max;
            std::tie(res, max) = countSpan(curr);
            if (prev < curr) {
                if (curr > max) {
                    // 0,1,5,1,7 - invalid because number in the fourth position lies in [2,5]
                    // and so in the fifth encoded position we can't something bigger than 5
                    return 0;
                }
                // It is time to possibly shrink stairs.
                // E.g if we had stairs 0,2,4,9,17 and current value is 5,
                // then we no more interested in 9 and 17, and we change stairs to 0,2,4,5.
                // That's because any number bigger than 9 or 17 also bigger than 5.
                const auto s = std::lower_bound(stairsBegin, stairsEnd, curr);
                stairsEnd = s;
                *stairsEnd++ = curr;
            }
            else {
                assert(curr < prev);
                auto it = std::lower_bound(stairsBegin, stairsEnd, curr);
                if (it == stairsEnd || *it != curr) {
                    // 0,5,1 is invalid sequence because original sequence lloks like this 5,>5,>1
                    // and there is no 1 in any of the two first positions, so
                    // it can't appear in the third position of the encoded array
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            spanLength = 1;
        }
        prev = curr;
    }
    res = countSpan(-1).first;
    return res;
}

template <class T> T normalizeMod(T a, T m) {
    if (a < 0) return a + m;
    return a;
}

template <class T> std::pair<T, std::pair<T, T>> extendedEuclidInternal(T a, T b) {
    T old_x = 1;
    T old_y = 0;
    T x = 0;
    T y = 1;
    while (true) {
        T q = a / b;
        T t = a - b * q;
        if (t == 0) {
            break;
        }
        a = b;
        b = t;
        t = x; x = old_x - x * q; old_x = t;
        t = y; y = old_y - y * q; old_y = t;
    }
    return std::make_pair(b, std::make_pair(x, y));
}

// Returns gcd and Bezout's coefficients
template <class T> std::pair<T, std::pair<T, T>> extendedEuclid(T a, T b) {
    if (a > b) {
        if (b == 0) return std::make_pair(a, std::make_pair(1, 0));
        return extendedEuclidInternal(a, b);
    }
    else {
        if (a == 0) return std::make_pair(b, std::make_pair(0, 1));
        auto p = extendedEuclidInternal(b, a);
        std::swap(p.second.first, p.second.second);
        return p;
    }
}

template <class T> T invMod(T a, T m) {
    auto p = extendedEuclid(a, m);
    assert(p.first == 1);
    return normalizeMod(p.second.first, m);
}


int CombinationsWithReplacement(int n, int k) {
    int res = 1;
    for (long long i = n; i < n + k; ++i) {
        res = res * i % Modulus;
    }
    int denom = 1;
    for (long long i = k; i > 0; --i) {
        denom = denom * i % Modulus;
    }
    res = res * (long long)invMod(denom, Modulus) % Modulus;
    return res;
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Only the above is needed for the Codility challenge. Below is to run on the command line.
//
// Compile with: gcc -std=gnu++14 -lc++ -lstdc++ array_recovery.cpp
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <string.h>

// Usage: 0 1 2,3, 4 M
// Last arg is M, the max value for an input.
// Remaining args are B (the output of the encoder) separated by commas and/or spaces
// Parentheses and brackets are ignored, so you can use the same input form as Codility's tests: ([1,2,3], M)
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int Max;
  std::vector<int> B;
  const char* delim = " ,[]()";

  if (argc < 2 ) {
    printf("Usage: %s M 0 1 2,3, 4... \n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    char* parse;
    parse = strtok(argv[i], delim);
    while (parse != NULL)
    {
       B.push_back(atoi(parse));
       parse = strtok (NULL, delim);
    }
  }
  Max = B.back();
  B.pop_back();

  printf("%d\n", solution(B, Max));
  return 0;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Only the above is needed for the Codility challenge. Below is to run on the command line.
//
// Compile with: gcc -std=gnu++14 -lc++ -lstdc++ array_recovery.cpp
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <string.h>

// Usage: M 0 1 2,3, 4
// first arg is M, the max value for an input.
// remaining args are B (the output of the encoder) separated by commas and/or spaces
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int Max;
  std::vector<int> B;
  const char* delim = " ,";

  if (argc < 3 ) {
    printf("Usage: %s M 0 1 2,3, 4... \n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  Max = atoi(argv[1]);
  for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
    char* parse;
    parse = strtok(argv[i], delim);
    while (parse != NULL)
    {
       B.push_back(atoi(parse));
       parse = strtok (NULL, delim);
    }
  }


  printf("%d\n", solution(B, Max));
  return 0;
}
```

Let's see an example:

> Max = 5
>   Array is
>     `0    1    3    0    1    1    3`
>     `1`
>     `1   2..5`
>     `1    3  4..5`
>     `1    3  4..5   1`
>     `1    3  4..5   1   2..5`
>     `1    3  4..5   1   2..5 >=..2` (sorry, for a cumbersome way of writing)
>     `1    3  4..5   1   3..5 >=..3 4..5`
>   Now count:
>     `1    1    2    1       3       2` which amounts to `12` total.

Comment: Thank you. Plese add a little more explanation. First, my C++ is rusty, what does `auto countSpan = [&](int curr)` mean? Second, how do you define _span_ boundaries. Third, how do you represent/store that a span of length 5 has to be in the range [n..m] and also contain the digits 5 and 9? Then, given that set of constraints, how do you calculate the number of combinations?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the explanation you added. I intend to give you the bonus, but I do have more questions. Please explain more specifically what a span is. How do you decide when one ends and the next one starts? If `7,7,2` and `curr` is `2` Why is the minimum `prev + 1`? Wouldn't max be `prev` otherwise output would be another `7` not `2`? Also, why are there zeros in all your stairs when zero can never appear in the input? I don't see where you shrink the length of the stairs: where do you do that?

Comment: @OldPro span is just a subsequence were all numbers are the same. In `1,1,2,2` we have two spans. At a certain moment, `prev` is exactly the number in the span (its *generator* we can say) we just passed through. So, when index is `2` (starting with `0`) `prev = 1` and span we have passed through is `1,1`. At this moment the minimum number possible to be in the original array in any of positions from span `1,1` is `prev + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2 > 1`.

Comment: @OldPro In the case of `7,7,2` If we have just finished span `7,7` the mimimum would be `8`, because `8` is the smallest number bigger than `7`.

Comment: @OldPro This line `stairsEnd = s;` shrinks the stairs. Employing `lower_bound` we find position of value not smaller than `curr` and we rewrite this number with `curr` and set end of stairs into this position. E.g. if we have stairs `0,1,5,7` and next value we encountered in encoded array is `3` then new stairs looks like `0,1,3`. We are not interested any more in `5` and `7`, because any upcoming value bigger than `5` or `7` is also bigger than `3` and `3` is apparently closer to it.

Comment: @OldPro keeping zero in stairs is important because we can encounter `0` in encoded array later on, the same as `1` or `82`, and we need to find this value in stairs array also.

Comment: @OldPro do you see how this is a similar stack "reconstruction" to what I proposed? And Yola's use of `CombinationsWithReplacement` seems there to count what I described as "bound non-increasing sequences" (please see my answer for an explanation of how that combinatoric is relevant). @Yola congrats on writing out a full solution! (I thought my idea of traversing backwards to reconstruct the stack leads to an O(n) solution - is there a reason not?)

Comment: Ah, I think I see why it makes more sense to go forward and O(n) may not be achievable - traversing backwards, if an upper bound on a section on the right needs updating. +1

Comment: @גלעדברקן With this input `[0,2,2,3,7,9,3] 10` your code returned
`[[2,2],["non_inc",1,3,10],[3,3],[7,7],[8,10],[9,7],[10,10],[4,9]]`, but i'm not sure that `[4,9]` is the valid range for the last position.

Comment: @Yola that code is unreliable. It was only meant as a rough sketch to illustrate the encoding. The logic you've implemented is clearly correct.

Comment: @Yola I see, while at `curr` you are setting the minimum for the `prev` span. I think I understand it all now. Please move your answers out of the comments and into your main answer so future readers don't have to scan the comments, and then I will award you the bonus.

Comment: @Yola I rearranged your code to put the most interesting stuff at the top and added `main()` but otherwise did not change any of your code. I added a lot more explanation to your answer. I hope you like the changes. Thank you for all of your work!

Comment: @OldPro That's definitely a good idea to put `solution` on top. Thank you too!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea. One known method to construct the output is to use a stack. We pop it while the element is greater or equal, then output the smaller element if it exists, then push the greater element onto the stack. Now what if we attempted to do this backwards from the output?

First we'll demonstrate the stack method using the c∅dility example.

```
[2, 5, 3, 7, 9, 6]
2: output 0, stack [2]
5: output 2, stack [2,5]
3: pop 5, output, 2, stack [2,3]
7: output 3, stack [2,3,7]
... etc.

Final output: [0, 2, 2, 3, 7, 3]
```

Now let's try reconstruction! We'll use `stack` both as the imaginary stack and as the reconstituted input:

```
(Input: [2, 5, 3, 7, 9, 6])
Output: [0, 2, 2, 3, 7, 3]

* Something >3 that reached 3 in the stack
stack = [3, 3 < *]

* Something >7 that reached 7 in the stack
but both of those would've popped before 3
stack = [3, 7, 7 < x, 3 < * <= x]

* Something >3, 7 qualifies
stack = [3, 7, 7 < x, 3 < * <= x]

* Something >2, 3 qualifies
stack = [2, 3, 7, 7 < x, 3 < * <= x]

* Something >2 and >=3 since 3 reached 2
stack = [2, 2 < *, 3, 7, 7 < x, 3 < * <= x]
```

Let's attempt your examples:

Example 1:

```
[0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4]

* Something >4
stack = [4, 4 < *]

* Something >3, 4 qualifies
stack = [3, 4, 4 < *]

* Something >2, 3 qualifies
stack = [2, 3, 4, 4 < *]

* The rest is non-increasing with lowerbound 2
stack = [y >= x, x >= 2, 2, 3, 4, >4]
```

Example 2:

```
[0, 0, 0, 4]

* Something >4
stack [4, 4 < *]

* Non-increasing
stack = [z >= y, y >= 4, 4, 4 < *]
```

Calculating the number of combinations is achieved by multiplying together the possibilities for all the sections. A section is either a bounded single cell; or a bound, non-increasing subarray of one or more cells. To calculate the latter we use the multi-choose binomial, `(n + k - 1) choose (k - 1)`. Consider that we can express the differences between the cells of a bound, non-increasing sequence of `3` cells as:

```
(ub - cell_3) + (cell_3 - cell_2) + (cell_2 - cell_1) + (cell_1 - lb) = ub - lb
```

Then the number of ways to distribute `ub - lb` into `(x + 1)` cells is

```
(n + k - 1) choose (k - 1)
or
(ub - lb + x) choose x

For example, the number of non-increasing sequences between
(3,4) in two cells is (4 - 3 + 2) choose 2 = 3: [3,3] [4,3] [4,4]

And the number of non-increasing sequences between
(3,4) in three cells is (4 - 3 + 3) choose 3 = 4: [3,3,3] [4,3,3] [4,4,3] [4,4,4]
```

(Explanation attributed to [Brian M. Scott](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/159220/75712).)

Rough JavaScript sketch (the code is unreliable; it's only meant to illustrate the encoding. The encoder lists [lower_bound, upper_bound], or a non-increasing sequence as [non_inc, length, lower_bound, upper_bound]):

```js
function f(A, M){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(A), M);
  let i = A.length - 1;
  let last = A[i];
  let s = [[last,last]];
  if (A[i-1] == last){
    let d = 1;
    s.splice(1,0,['non_inc',d++,last,M]);
    while (i > 0 && A[i-1] == last){
      s.splice(1,0,['non_inc',d++,last,M]);
      i--
    }
  } else {
    s.push([last+1,M]);
    i--;
  }
  if (i == 0)
    s.splice(0,1);

  for (; i>0; i--){
    let x = A[i];

    if (x < s[0][0])
      s = [[x,x]].concat(s);

    if (x > s[0][0]){
      let [l, _l] = s[0];
      let [lb, ub] = s[1];
      s[0] = [x+1, M];
      s[1] = [lb, x];
      s = [[l,_l], [x,x]].concat(s);
    }

    if (x == s[0][0]){
      let [l,_l] = s[0];
      let [lb, ub] = s[1];
      let d = 1;
      s.splice(0,1);
      while (i > 0 && A[i-1] == x){
        s =
    [['non_inc', d++, lb, M]].concat(s);
        i--;
      }
      if (i > 0)
        s = [[l,_l]].concat(s);
    }
  }

  // dirty fix
  if (s[0][0] == 0)
    s.splice(0,1);

  return s; 
}

var a = [2, 5, 3, 7, 9, 6]
var b = [0, 2, 2, 3, 7, 3]
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(b,10)));
b = [0,0,0,4]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(b,10)));
b = [0,2,0,0,0,4]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(b,10)));
b = [0,0,0,2,3,4]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(b,10)));
b = [0,2,2]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(b,4)));
b = [0,3,5,6]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(b,10)));
b = [0,0,3,0]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(b,10)));
```

Comment: I don't see how this helps.

Comment: @OldPro which part do you doubt - being able to reverse engineer the would-have-been stack sequence or extrapolating from it the count of possibilities?

Comment: @OldPro I think the logic to reconstitute the stack process is feasible, and there's a fairly straightforward combinatoric to count bound non-increasing sequences. I'll try to code something if I have some time.

Comment: @I don't see how the stack helps the reverse engineering. I've figured out how to count the results if I have lower and upper bounds on all the inputs.

Comment: @OldPro I think the would-have-been stack idea can help formulate an algorithm to produce an expression like the final ones in the three examples in my answer (and include M, codility's upperbound, where appropriate). Given those expressions, could you deduce the count of possibilities? Could you please add an example of how you'd count the results given lower and upper bounds? The expressions I'm talking about seem to me would be a single expression per input (well, technically "output" :) did you mean for there to be more than one expression per problem input (meaning "output")?